# preferred apps of the same kind while initial device setup/startup in a custom ROM

Tags: android, configuration, startup, homescreen

we are building our own AOSP/ custom ROM with latest version of Lollipop.

What we are trying to archieve is to build custom ROM with two Homescreens pre-installed on device.
One will be standard Andoid "Launcher3" and the other is our own home screen app "foobarhome". So far so good :-)

Our current initial device startup phase roughly looks as follows:
- device boot animation
- GMS SetupWizard (Wi-Fi, Language, Google Acount setup, etc.)
**** device reaches setup complete status ****
- ResolverActivity starts showing selection between our own Home app "foobarhome" and Launcher3 (>>BAD GUY<<)
- we have to select "foobarhome" to run "always" 
- our Home screen app is up and running

**PROBLEM:** Unfortunately we will get the ResolverActivity right after GMS SetupWizard has finished.
ResolverActivity gives us selection between Launcher3 and our home screen app and we have to select our home app manually (run always).
**GOAL:** Directly start our home app without ResolverActivity in between.

**PREPERATION:**
During building the custom ROM and executing all ours and Androids make files, we copy an so called **preferred-activities-home.xml** to **system/etc/preferred-apps/** on the device.

in our whatever.mk we have following lines of code:
preferred application setup:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    myLocalPath/preferred_activities/preferred-activities-home.xml:system/etc/preferred-apps/preferred-activities-home.xml
```

and the content of such **preferred-activities-home.xml** look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<preferred-activities>
    <item name="com.example.foobarhome/.MainActivity" match="100000" set="2">
        <set name="com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher" />
        <set name="com.example.foobarhome/.MainActivity" />
        <filter>
            <action name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <cat name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <cat name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </filter>
    </item>
</preferred-activities>
```

As you might know **frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/andoid/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java** and **./Settings.java** classes are processing such config.

**Our ANALYSIS:**
1) GMS SetupWizard just started (select language page)
  --> execute adb **"shell dumpsys package preferred-xml"** or on device file dir check content of file: **data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml** 
  --> look for xml node block:

```
<preferred-activities> ... </preferred-activities>
```

our output is:

```
<item name="com.example.foobarhome/.MainActivity" match="100000" always="true" set="4">
    <set name="com.android.settings/.CryptKeeper" />
    <set name="com.google.android.setupwizard/.SetupWizardActivity" />
    <set name="com.example.foobarhome/.MainActivity" />
    <set name="com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher" />
    <filter>
        <action name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <cat name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <cat name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </filter>
</item>
```

2) GMS SetupWizard finished, SetupWizard UI disappeared and ResolverActivity is shown
  --> possible selection:

```
  Use foobarhome as HOME
  buttons "always" and "just once"
  --------------------------------
  Use a different app
  Launcher3
```

--> check package-restrictions.xml file in device again and 
  the output is:

```
<item name="com.example.foobarhome/.MainActivity" match="100000" always="false" set="0">
    <filter>
        <action name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <cat name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <cat name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </filter>
</item>
```

Why Launcher3 is getting lost here?

3) after selecting our foobarhome app to run always, we check the package-restrictions.xml again and behold - there is what we expected to see after GMS SetupWizard finished.
Output is:

```
<item name="com.example.foobarhome/.MainActivity" match="100000" always="true" set="2">
    <set name="com.example.foobarhome/.MainActivity" />
    <set name="com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher" />
    <filter>
        <action name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <cat name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <cat name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </filter>
</item>
```

In general these preferred-activities.xml approach works but somehow it doesn't during initial device startup/setup.
We wonder why we loose the 2nd home app(Launcher3) in the package-restrictions.xml on the way to the ResolverActivity.

**QUESTIONS:**
**Q1:** Is there a way to pre-select an home screen app in the Settings.apk (packages/apps/Settings) maybe via **aosp_root/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/res/Configuration.java**.
Would this maybe solve the issue?

**Q2:** On device in data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml we saw two new xml nodes which got introduced by Lollipop (compared to KitKat).
    Those are called `<persistent-preferred-activities />` and `<crossProfile-intent-filters />`. 
    What are they for and how to use?
    What would be the syntax of child elements in `<persistent-preferred-activities />`?
    Any public available android documentation about it?

**MAIN QUESTION:** Any idea how we can solve it by not getting the ResolverActiviy during inital device startup/setup?

Answer (score 0):

For Q1: I think you can do something just like ChooseActivity do. the key is to find a proper time to execute before Launcher,  As I know, Provision is the best place to do this.
you can call `addPreferredActivity()` which is carried by `PackageManager`
before the Provision disabled itself.